# how to add a object in scene to a mesh without changing its position in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to keep the position of an object in scene and want to change the parent of that object from scene to any other mesh.here is a sample code
http://plnkr.co/edit/fpjsUkOA0rH6FvG4DL6Z?p=preview

in this example when am trying to add the sphere to box it's `position` is changing.i want to keep the original position .try to remove comment in line 35 ,the spehere is moving towards box.i want to keep its position and make sphere box's child
http://plnkr.co/edit/fpjsUkOA0rH6FvG4DL6Z?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you add the sphere to the group, you just need to substract the group's position from the sphere's position to keep it in its original world position.

```js
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});

  var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 15, 5);
  var box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, material);

  var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 32, 32 );
  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, material);
  sphere.position.set(0, 10, 0);
  sphere.updateMatrix();

  var group = new THREE.Object3D();
  group.translateX(6);
  group.updateMatrix();

  // if you add sphere to group object
  group.add(box);
  group.add(sphere);
  scene.add(group);

  var m = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(group.matrixWorld);
  sphere.applyMatrix(m);

  // if you add sphere to box
  group.add(box);
  box.add(sphere);
  scene.add(group);

  var m = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(box.matrixWorld);
  sphere.applyMatrix(m);

  console.log(group.position, sphere.position);
```

Comment: i dont want to make a group. i want to make one mesh child of other mesh and move them together.when i am trying to add child to parent child position is moving . parent.add(child) when i do this i want preserve the postion scale and rotation of both parent and child

Comment: Well, I said group, because in your plunker named the `THREE.Object3D` `group`. And you added the box and the sphere to that group. But it doesn't matter what the parent object is. You always need to take the parent's matrix. So, to keep position, rotation and scale @kaigorodov answer is correct. I also update my answer.

Comment: thanks for your response..i am trying all these using collada loaded models and its not working there .and the child object is moving according to the parents reference axis.but i want to make translation of child with respect to world coordinates..and am new to webGl and three.js can you pls suggest some good books or tutorial for my guidance will be very helpful for me since i don't have much knowledge about three.js.

Comment: Here is something about [Matrix Transformations](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Matrix_transformations). If you download the whole Three.js package, there are also lots of examples for many aspects. For me those were quite useful if I wanted to use a specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

If question relies only to `position` then the answer of Brakebein may be correct. But if you need also to revert `scale` and `rotation`, then you should make something like this, I think:

```
var inversionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
inversionMatrix.getInverse( parentObject.matrix );
childObject.applyMatrix(inversionMatrix);
```